# EF Core Add-Migration target a specific project in a solution

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-5.0

Since adding DbContext to a second project in my solution, the syntax previously used for adding a new migration has gone out the window. I can't find the answer in knowing how to target a specific project for creating the new migration.

Using Package Manager Console I've tried various different commands but all fail:

```
Add-Migration InitialMigration1 -OutputDir "Data/Migrations" -Context SeqDbContext -Project SeqLogger-API -StartupProject SeqLogger-API -Namespace OIS_V1.0.0
```

I get the build started message for approx 10 seconds and the fails. Worth noting that I have the same folder directory structure in both projects i.e. myProjectName/Data/Migrations

Below is a screenshot of my current solution:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this was not obvious at first. The issue in my case what that there was some outstanding errors present in some code in one of my **other** projects in the solution, **NOT** the one I was trying to add the migration to.

And because I wasn't trying to startup the project that had the code errors, I knew nothing about it until I started uninstalling some EF Core Nuget packages and then suddenly the warnings for this other project started showing as per screenshot below.

[image]

So I quickly corrected the errors in this other project and was now able to run the migration for the new project in question simply using the following:

```
Add-Migration InitialMigration -context SeqDbContext -OutputDir "Data/Migrations"
```

So the lessons learned here is that the "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" and package manager wont allow any migrations unless ALL projects in your solution are ready to go i.e. there are no outstanding code errors in other projects than the one you're trying to add the migration to.

The final tip I also learnt is that targeting the required project to add a migration to is is a simple case of selecting the required project in the dropdown select shown at the top of the package manager console (which in my case was correct) can see that from the screenshot in my original question.